# Генерация электронного адреса из списка. Почему происходит бесконечный цикл предложенной функции?

Tags: python, файлы

Имеется задача :

необходимо написать программу, удовлетворяющую следующим требованиям:

1. Программа должна читать исходный текстовый файл
2. Программа должна содержать функцию, представленную ниже, для создания почтовых адресов
3. Программа должна заполнить пустой столбец с почтовыми адресами в исходном файле и перезаписать его
4. Почтовый адрес должен создаваться только для тех, у кого заполнены все остальные поля - Имя, Фамилия, Телефонный номер, Город
5. Телефонный номер считается валидным, если он состоит из 7 цифр, в противном случае информация невалидна и программа не должна создавать почтовый адрес сотруднику
   После выполнения вашей программы исходный текстовый файл должен быть заполнен информацией с почтовыми адресами сотрудников.

Файл формата txt с содержимым:

```
EMAIL, NAME, LAST_NAME, TEL, CITY
, Ivan, Abramov, 7776514, Moscow
, Alexey, Nikolaev, 1348520, Moscow
, Marina, Shapar, 1111110, Moscow
, Dmitriy, Vasilyev, 0000000, Kazan
, Ekaterina, Ilyina, , St.Petersburg
, Anastasiya, Grigoryan, 1928421, Ekaterinburg
, Andrey, Fedorov, 85212384, Minsk
, Alexey, Lisitsyn, 1239532, Tver
, Dariya, Abramova, 7163908, Moscow
, Alexandr, Evdokimov, 482, Volokolamsk
, Nataliya, Kostina, 9031433, Moscow
, Nikolay, Ermolin, 8539233, St.Petersburg
, , , , 
, Vladimir, Solovovo, 4758395, St.Petersburg
, Vladimir, Ivanov, 4827594, Novosibirsk
, Sergey, Nikolaev, 1294375, Sarov
, Ivan, Ivanov, 8532354, Kazan
, Konstantin, Semenov, 8532286, Moscow
, Grigoriy, Smirnov, 3249235, Kaliningrad
, Vasiliy, , 7123465, Moscow
, Alexandr, Lashko, 9548324, St.Petersburg
, sdfsdf, dwfef, 9994532, Rostov
, Oksana, Edger, 8548433, Kostroma
, Olga, Bogomolova, 8953253, Moscow
, Evgeniy, Strizh, 1123313, Krasnodar
, Valentina, Sergach, 12345567, St.Petersburg
, Polina, Volskaya, 1394542, Vladimir
, Fedor, Malinin, 9453223, Moscow
, Olga, Pahomova, 8543231, Moscow
, ffff, ffff, ffff, fffff
, Stepan, Bogdanov, 4564624, St.Petersburg
, Dmitriy, Smirnov, 9355r24, Kazan
, Valeria, Kolokolkina, 12O4352, St.Petersburg
, Ivan, Sobolev, 2350223, Kirov
, Kristina, Orlova, 1342349, Talnakh
, Alexandr, Ermolin, 2345234, Mozhaysk
, Ekaterina, Vasilevskaya, 9583573, Moscow
, Tatiana, Koroleva, 8674532, Vidnoe
, Elena, Moskvina, 7584294, Moscow
, , , 8954245, Moscow
, Mikhail, Sinev, 5964353, St.Petersburg
, NO_NAME, NO_NAME, 2856735, Kaliningrad
, Anastasiya, Boshich, 9654534, Omsk
, Svetlana, Kapustina, 9476353, Moscow
, Boris, Nikolaev, 9583583, Moscow
, Andrey, Mozgvin, 8537572, Krasnodar
, Oksana, Bogatyreva, 8743565, St.Petersburg
, Kseniya, Nosatenko, 1234194, Yaroslavl
, fwefwgwgwfds, sfewrfw, 9584356, Pskov
, Konstantin, Grigoriev, 1284575, Moscow
```

Для работы представленной для решения задачи функции необходим список списков с именами и фамилиями, а для него нужно сконвертировать столбцы в строки. С этой задачей я справился, но не могу понять почему предложенная функция уходит в бесконечный цикл. Можете помочь разобраться?
Без этого не получается перейти к решению пунктов 3,4 и 5

```
f = open('/task_file.txt', 'r+')

def email_gen(list_of_names):
    emails = []
    for i in list_of_names:
        letter = 1
        while i[1] + '.' + i[0][0:letter] + '@company.io' in emails:
            letter+=1
        emails.append(i[1] + '.' + i[0][0:letter] + '@company.io')
    return emails
#Функция принимает список списков [['Имя_1', 'Фамилия_1'], ['Имя_2', 'Фамилия_2'], ['Имя_3', 'Фамилия_3']] 
#из имен и фамилий list_of_names. Далее создается пустой список emails, который в ходе выполнения, заполнится почтовыми адресами. 
#Запускается цикл для каждого списка из имени и фамилии ['Имя_1', 'Фамилия_1']. Устанавливается окончание среза letter = 1. 
#Далее проходит проверка на совпадение, если в списке адресов уже есть такой же адрес (например имя и фамилия сотрудников совпадают), то срез i[0][0:letter] увеличивается на 1 символ. 
#После в список адресов добавляется новый адрес. Адреса присваиваются пользователям по следующей формуле: берется фамилия сотрудника, добавляется точка, затем добавляется первая буква имени и остаточная часть '@company.io'. 
#Если имена и фамилии сотрудников совпадают, к первой букве имени добавляется вторая и т.д.
def read_col(fname, col=1, convert=str, sep=None):
    with open(fname) as fobj:
         return [convert(line.split(sep=sep)[col]) for line in fobj]
#Функция для конвертации столбца в список
namez = read_col('/task_file.txt')
#создание списка имен  
lnamez = read_col('/task_file.txt', col=2)
#создание списка фамилий
zipped = [list(t) for t in zip(namez, lnamez)]
#создание списка списков из имен и фамилий
list_of_names = zipped
email_gen(list_of_names)
print (emails)
#пытаюсь проверить какой список емейлов получился
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка заключается в том, что Ваша функция при получении двух единиц данных с пустыми фамилией и именем не может дальше продолжить свою работу, т.к. он постоянно пытается проверить вторую строку. Первая строка уже была проверена => электронная почта уже есть `.@company.io`, а вот у второй строки постоянно получается `.@company.io`, и увеличение `letter` даёт такую же почту — отсюда и вечный цикл.

Также проблемой является то, что при начале всех строк стоят пробельные символы (из текста), из-за чего все строки становятся непустыми и состоящими из пробелов.

Для начала избавьтесь от пробелов вначале, используя функцию [`lstrip()`](https://www.journaldev.com/23625/python-trim-string-rstrip-lstrip-strip), а затем добавьте проверку на непустоту И имени, И фамилии:

```py
f = open('task_file.txt', 'r+')

def email_gen(list_of_names):
    emails = []
    for i in list_of_names:
        if not (i[0] or i[1]): # если имя и фамилия пустые
            continue # не засчитываем
        letter = 1
        while i[1] + '.' + i[0][0:letter] + '@company.io' in emails:
            letter+=1
        emails.append(i[1] + '.' + i[0][0:letter] + '@company.io')
    return emails
#Функция принимает список списков [['Имя_1', 'Фамилия_1'], ['Имя_2', 'Фамилия_2'], ['Имя_3', 'Фамилия_3']] 
#из имен и фамилий list_of_names. Далее создается пустой список emails, который в ходе выполнения, заполнится почтовыми адресами. 
#Запускается цикл для каждого списка из имени и фамилии ['Имя_1', 'Фамилия_1']. Устанавливается окончание среза letter = 1. 
#Далее проходит проверка на совпадение, если в списке адресов уже есть такой же адрес (например имя и фамилия сотрудников совпадают), то срез i[0][0:letter] увеличивается на 1 символ. 
#После в список адресов добавляется новый адрес. Адреса присваиваются пользователям по следующей формуле: берется фамилия сотрудника, добавляется точка, затем добавляется первая буква имени и остаточная часть '@company.io'. 
#Если имена и фамилии сотрудников совпадают, к первой букве имени добавляется вторая и т.д.
def read_col(fname, col=1, convert=str, sep=','):
    with open(fname) as fobj:
        return [convert(line.split(sep=sep)[col].lstrip()) for line in fobj]
        #lstrip убирает все пробелы в начале строки
#Функция для конвертации столбца в список
namez = read_col('task_file.txt')
#создание списка имен  
lnamez = read_col('task_file.txt', col=2)
#создание списка фамилий
zipped = [list(t) for t in zip(namez, lnamez)]
#создание списка списков из имен и фамилий
list_of_names = zipped
emails = email_gen(list_of_names)
print (emails)
#пытаюсь проверить какой список емейлов получился
```